# Quick replies on Facebook messenger bot don't have a payload

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots, payload

I'm using this code for a quick reply button in a facebook messenger bot (JavaScript):

```
    var message = {
    "attachment": {
        "type": "template",
            "payload": {
                "template_type": "generic",
                "elements": [{
                    "title": "Order a cucumber",
                    "subtitle": "A cucumber",
                    "image_url": "SOME_LINK_HERE",
                    "buttons": [
                        {"type": "postback",
                        "title": "Order",
                        "payload": "cucumber"},
                        {"type": "postback",
                        "title": "Order & Finish",
                        "payload": "cucumberf"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Order a tomato",
                    "subtitle": "A tomato",
                    "image_url": "SOME_LINK_HERE",
                    "buttons": [
                        {"type": "postback",
                        "title": "Order",
                        "payload": "tomato"},
                        {"type": "postback",
                        "title": "Order & Finish",
                        "payload": "tomatof"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Order a cake",
                    "subtitle": "A cake",
                    "image_url": "SOME_LINK_HERE",
                    "buttons": [
                        {"type": "postback",
                        "title": "Order",
                        "payload": "cake"},
                        {"type": "postback",
                        "title": "Order & Finish",
                        "payload": "cakef"}
                    ]
                }]
            }
    },
    "quick_replies": [
        {"content_type": "text",
        "title": "Main menu",
        "payload": "mainMenu"}
    ]};
```

When I'm trying to get the payload of the quick reply button (`event.message.quick_reply`), it says it's undefined. But for the other fields it returns what it should (like the "seq" field or the "text" field.
What am I doing wrong, and how can I use the quick replies buttons' payload?

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows you how to get all the thing the user sent/clicked:

```
// handle bot's anwser
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$senderId = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];

// gets the text the user sent to you
$messageText = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

// gets the payload of the button
$buttonPayLoad = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['postback']['payload'];

// gets the payload of the quick replay
$quickReplyPayLoad = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['quick_reply']['payload'];
```